MS Edge/Chrome (Chromium) stopped showing Response/Preview
I have recently observed that I do no longer have preview/response in the Dev Tools of Chrome & Edge for $batch calls to an OData service.

Nevertheless, in Firefox for example I am able to see it without any problems:

I tested this with Brave & Arc as well - there I have exactly the same issue so I assume it is a Chromium thing.
Does anyone have an idea what is the issue and how to fix it?

It seems to be caused by multipart/* as is described in this thread. Looks like the Dev Team has been working on it and may release a fix in Stable in the next versions. In Chrome Canary 131.0.6741.0 the issue is fixed.

Thank you! Installed Chrome Canary - it is working. Hopefully will be a part of stable release soon.
